# Using "checkpoints" in netlogo

Tags: netlogo

i am designing a program where an aircraft will travel between two points on my "airspace". However, in between those 2 points, i have 5 "checkpoints" where the aircraft will make a decision every time it passes each checkpoint. The code i have written for the checkpoints are as follows :

```
to setup-areas
  ask patches [
    ifelse pxcor >= 14 
    [  set nonedist? true ]
    [  set nonedist? false  ]
    ifelse pxcor > 10.8 and pxcor < 14 and pycor <= -2.5 and pycor > -4.5
    [  set twelvedist? true  ]
    [  set twelvedist? false  ]
    ifelse pxcor > 7.6 and pxcor <= 10.8 and pycor <= -4.5 and pycor >= -7.5
    [  set ninedist? true  ]
    [  set ninedist? false  ]
    ifelse pxcor > 4.4 and pxcor <= 7.6 and pycor < -7.5 and pycor >= -8.5
    [  set sixdist? true  ]
    [  set sixdist? false  ]
    ifelse pxcor > 1.2 and pxcor <= 4.4 and pycor < -10.5 and pycor >= -11.5
    [  set threedist? true  ]
    [  set threedist? false  ]
    ifelse pxcor >= -2 and pxcor <= 1.2 and pycor < -12.5 and pycor >= -13
    [  set onedist? true  ]
    [  set onedist? false  ]
    ifelse pxcor < -2 and pycor < -13.5
    [  set zerodist? true  ]
    [  set zerodist? false  ]
  ]
end
```

The aircraft doest seem to be following the areas it is in. Any help is greatly appreciated!

The code to get the aircraft to execute some action upon entering a specific zone is as follows:

```
to go
  ask aircrafts
  [
    while [nonedist? = true]   [ pre-twelve ]
    while [twelvedist? = true] [ twelve-to-nine ]
  ]
  tick
end
```

Comment: You haven't given us any code about the aircraft. Show us the code that you have written that is supposed to tell the aircraft to follow the checkpoints.

Comment: Specifically on the code you have given us, it might be easier if you have one variable for patches that is something like checkpoint-number (with 0 if not a checkpoint) as otherwise you will have a large number of variables to work through every time you want to interact with a checkpoint.

Comment: Hi @JenB, thanks again for your help. I am not trying to get the aircraft to follow specifically a path or checkpoint. As long as the aircraft is in the zone of that checkpoint, it is considered passing that checkpoint. This will allow multiple aircrafts to have variable paths

Comment: nonedist = distance before first checkpoint

twelvedist = FIRST checkpoint. Between (12000 ft and 9000ft)

ninedist = SECOND checkpoint. Between (9000ft and 6000ft )

and so on...

Comment: Stylistic comment about the use of booleans: you don't have to do `ifelse pxcor >= 14  [ set nonedist? true ] [ set nonedist? ]`; you can (and should) do directly: `set nonedist? (pxcor >= 14)`. And when check your boolean, avoid `= true`: you can directly do `if nonedist? [...]`.

Comment: @NicolasPayette Thank you for your comment. I will amend accordingly

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an answer but I do have a diagnostic suggestion.

First, change your setup-areas procedure to make things a bit more visible. The following will mark the patches where the aircraft should do something.

```
to setup-areas
  ask patches [
    ifelse pxcor >= 14 
    [  set nonedist? true set pcolor red]
    [  set nonedist? false  ]
    ifelse pxcor > 10.8 and pxcor < 14 and pycor <= -2.5 and pycor > -4.5
    [  set twelvedist? true  set pcolor red]
    [  set twelvedist? false  ]
    ifelse pxcor > 7.6 and pxcor <= 10.8 and pycor <= -4.5 and pycor >= -7.5
    [  set ninedist? true  set pcolor red]
    [  set ninedist? false  ]
    ifelse pxcor > 4.4 and pxcor <= 7.6 and pycor < -7.5 and pycor >= -8.5
    [  set sixdist? true  set pcolor red]
    [  set sixdist? false  ]
    ifelse pxcor > 1.2 and pxcor <= 4.4 and pycor < -10.5 and pycor >= -11.5
    [  set threedist? true  set pcolor red]
    [  set threedist? false  ]
    ifelse pxcor >= -2 and pxcor <= 1.2 and pycor < -12.5 and pycor >= -13
    [  set onedist? true  set pcolor red]
    [  set onedist? false  ]
    ifelse pxcor < -2 and pycor < -13.5
    [  set zerodist? true  set pcolor red]
    [  set zerodist? false  ]
  ]
end
```

Then change what they should be doing when they hit a checkpoint.

```
to go
  ask aircrafts
  [
    if [nonedist? = true] [ set color blue ]
    if [twelvedist? = true] [ set color blue ]
  ]
  tick
end
```

This will let you see if the interaction occurs as you expect. Then change your `go` code back and modify your action code so that, for example:

```
to pre-twelve
  set color blue
  type "My height is " print varname   ; where varname is whatever is being changed
  < then all the code you already have in the pre-twelve procedure>
end
```

The point is to work out which procedure isn't happening and from there, to work out why it's not happening. There is simply insufficient information in your question to have any chance of working out what's wrong.

Comment: Thank you @JenB. It definitely provided me the visuals to understand how it works!